# Prevent Activation Email on creation - Wait for Admin Approval

Tags: activation

I would like to prevent the 'Activate Your Account' w/link from being sent when users first registers via a front-end public registration.

**I need activation to happen manually via an Admin.**

I have *temporarily* blocked this by commenting it out in `/craft/app/controllers/UsersController.php` 
Obviously I do not want to go to production with this, so how can I disable via a plugin?

The code in question appears on line 1049:

```
//
        if ($verifyNewEmail)
        {
            // Temporarily set the unverified email on the UserModel so the verification email goes to the
            // right place
            $originalEmail = $user->email;
            $user->email = $user->unverifiedEmail;

            if ($isNewUser)
            {
                // Send the activation email
                // $emailSent = craft()->users->sendActivationEmail($user);
                $emailSent = true; // *** NOT TRUE, BUT HACKED ***
            }
            else
            {
                // Send the standard verification email
                $emailSent = craft()->users->sendNewEmailVerifyEmail($user);
            }

            if (!$emailSent)
            {
                craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('User saved, but couldn’t send verification email. Check your email settings.'));
            }

            // Put the original email back into place
            $user->email = $originalEmail;
        }
```

Comment: Seems like you just want to uncheck "Verify Email Addresses?" under Settings->Users->Settings?

Comment: For future reference: if there is no setting for such tasks the best way to solve this would be to create a custom plugin with a controller that extends the UserController where you overwrite the things you want to change

Comment: @BradBell thanks that worked. I must have had something else in-flux during my original attempts with that Admin setting

Comment: @JeremyA Awesome... if you want to add it as an official answer, I'll throw some points/reputation your way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BradBell - I just needed to use the Admin setting.

> Seems like you just want to uncheck "Verify Email Addresses?" under >Settings->Users->Settings